# Add an OpenId and my Reputation Disappears

Tags: support, openid

I originally chose FB as my OpenId when using Stackoverflow, but I'd like to switch and use Google. When I click "add openid" on my Stackoverflow profile and choose Google all of my reputation disappears and I appear to be a completely different user. I was assuming/hoping that this would associate both openids with my account.

Am I doing something wrong? Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a duplicate account that's a year old -- so when you click "add" you are logged into duplicate account #2.

I went ahead and merged these for you.